# Android Facebook ApiException: Invalid Application

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting Facebook ApiException: Invalid Application error when I try to log in with some other account apart from my Developer Account and even my sandbox mode is off as I have checked with other posts having same issue.Thanks in advance.

10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721): com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: ApiException:Invalid application 165081033652784
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at com.facebook.Session.handleAuthorizationResult(Session.java:1078)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at com.facebook.Session.onActivityResult(Session.java:554)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult(UiLifecycleHelper.java:144)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at com.punchh.base.FacebookActivity.onActivityResult(FacebookActivity.java:141)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
10-24 17:03:24.355: W/System.err(13721):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: can you please post the logcat error

Comment: please check the logcat error

Comment: did you paste the same app_id as it in your facebook app settings page?

Comment: yes iam using the same..as i can login with my developer account with that app_id.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problems, check the facebook's application configuration, maybe is on Developer Mode (SandBox). Only developer users added in developer roles can see the app and use it.
Try changing the app configuration to public app.

Take a note: If you set like "Public App" all facebook user will be able to see your app. If your application is in development period it's better work with Facebook Roles. When your app is in release period it is time to change to "Public App"

Comment: Correct! I had the same problem as the one from the question and making it "available to the general public" solve the issue - now I can log in with with any account. Thanks.