# Facebook: The proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being installed previously

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm developing an Android app with Facebook SDK 3.8.
It works correctly for me. 
But it NOT work for my friend or any other facebook account.
It notify "`The proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being installed previously.`" and without any exception.

Note: I have set this app on facebook to "Live and available to all users" in Setting & Review tab. 

My request permission:

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info, user_friends, read_friendlists, manage_friendlists"));
```

Comment: You need to separate "read" and "publish" permissions.Before you can request a publish permission, you need to get at least "basic_info" first, which is a read permission. Use `setReadPermission` and `setPublishPermission` this methods.

Comment: I referenced this answer but currently, it still works for me, it only dont work for any one.

Comment: check @Cesardl [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564663/android-facebook-apiexception-invalid-application/20690832#20690832). If it's helpful to you.

Comment: In the question, I wrote that: I have set this app on facebook to "Live and available to all users" in Setting & Review tab.
I dont know, is that enough or need any else.