# Error facebook integration with android application

Tags: android, facebook

[image]

I tried to integrate facebook login with my android application,I got this error.  I created appId with my package and include that app id in my application also.

Comment: which account you used to login ?  is it different than what you used to setup your app ?

Comment: @Ramakrishna how do you resolve problem?

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear "*This app is still in development mode*".

In https://developers.facebook.com, on the app configuration > Roles, you should add facebook account with developers privileges.

[image: facebook developer dashboard]

Check my complete answer in this post: [Android Facebook ApiException: Invalid Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564663/android-facebook-apiexception-invalid-application/20690832#20690832)